# How to delete HTML row using jQuery and then update to database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Currently the following code is able to make the first 2 columns editable and process it and have it sent to PHP and update to db.
I then tried a few code to remove a particular row with the JavaScript code but now it caused that editable and delete to not work altogether.

How to make both editable and delete row work again?

*Edit* the editable uses source from [jquery.jeditable.mini.js](http://www.appelsiini.net/download/jquery.jeditable.mini.js)

**HTML code:**

```
<table>
<tbody><tr>
    <th>Room Types</th>
    <th>Acronym</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
</tr>
<tr id="row-0">
    <td><div class="edit" id="Deluxe Family">Deluxe Family</div></td>
    <td><div class="edit" id="DLX (2K)">DLX (2K)</div></td>
    <td><div class="delete" id="DLX (2K)"><span class="ui-button-text">X</span></div></td>
</tr>
<tr id="row-1">
    <td><div class="edit" id="Deluxe Queen">Deluxe Queen</div></td>
    <td><div class="edit" id="DLX (2Q)">DLX (2Q)</div></td>
    <td><div class="delete" id="DLX (2Q)"><span class="ui-button-text">X</span></div></td>
</tr></tbody>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.edit').editable('process.php', {
        loadurl   : 'load.php',
        id        : 'rt_code',
        name      : 'rt_codevalue',
        indicator : 'Saving...',
        tooltip   : 'Click to edit...'
    });
    $('.delete').click(function(){
        var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var rowElement = $(this).parent().parent(); //grab the row

        $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'process.php',
                data: delete_id : del_id,
                success:function(data) {
                    if(data == "YES") {
                       rowElement.fadeOut(500).remove();
                    } 
                    else {
                    }
                }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['rt_code'])  {
    echo $_POST['rt_codevalue'];
}

if(isset($_POST['delete_id'])) {
    $data = "DELETE FROM roomtype WHERE RT_CODE = ".$_POST['delete_id'];
    if(query($data)) {
        echo "YES";
    }
}
```

Comment: `id` is unique and you're using the same id twice.

Comment: are you getting any erros on browser console?

Comment: how are you adding the rows.

Comment: @Itay Gal, i changed the value of ID to unique but still break editable and delete.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar, no i'm not getting any error.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar, i have php code to extract those information from the db and display it in above html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess error is in your jquery ajax code
change it to as following,

```
$.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'process.php',
            data: {delete_id : del_id},
            success:function(data) {
                if(data == "YES") {
                   rowElement.fadeOut(500).remove();
                } 
                else {
                }
            }
    });
```

actually the data you have passed seems like an object but you forgot to put braces '{}' i mean

```
  data: delete_id : del_id,
```

should be

```
data: {delete_id : del_id},
```

Comment: This still didn't remove the table row. It does solve the edit issue. Any other method?

Comment: I would suggest you alert the response from the AJAX script may be the response is not YES so that it is not getting in to the 'if' condition. i dont see any error in the code which is supposed to remove the table row.

Comment: I just tried again the answer given, yes it does work now, it is my process.php issue. I can't seems to vote your answer as i do not have 15 reputation yet. will come back and give you a vote once i gathered 15 reputation. Thanks!

Comment: U r welcome mate. i am glad i cud help. you can just mark my answer as 'Accepted Answer' as the owner of the question.